# Can't access Postgres running with docker-compose from WebStorm (JetBrains)

Tags: postgresql, docker, intellij-idea, webstorm

I have the following `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  postgres-service:
    image: postgres:12.3
    env_file:
      - .env
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
    volumes:
      - /postgres/data/
```

This is my `.env`:

```
POSTGRES_USER=app_postgres_user
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=foobar
POSTGRES_DB=app_database
```

I know `postgres-service` is working because I connect manually to the service and it works with following commands:

```
docker-compose run postgres-service bash # connect to postgres-service
psql --host=postgres-service --username=app_postgres_user --dbname=app_database
```

But when I try to connect from within "Webstorm > Database" I get this error:

```
The connection attempt failed.
java.net.UnknownHostException: postgres-service.
```

Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Try `localhost` instead of postgres service name.

Comment: Webstorm is running on the same machine as the docker host?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If Webstorm is running on the same host as the container, replace `postgres-service` with `localhost`.

If it is running elsewhere, replace `postgres-service` with the IP address of the docker host machine where the container resides.

I used your docker-compose and connected with DBeaver with these settings:

[image]

Your postgres container resides in a virtual network (e.g.: 172.17.0.0/16). By default there is no route from your machine to that network.

When you use

```
ports:
      - 'src:dest'
```

...in your `docker-compose.yml` file, a DNAT rule is created from your `host:src` to the `container:dest` and that's the reason of using `localhost:src` or the IP address of the docker host.

Comment: thanks bro that helped a lot, and the extra bit of info now helps me understand better what is going on ;)

Comment: So basically postgres-service is just a tag/label for connecting between different docker services. But outside of it, it behaves as any other normal program.

Comment: You can compare the `postgres-service` with a DNS entry that resolves to one of the IP addresses of the containers that is beneath that service(in this case it is just one, but it works the same also when you have multiple replicas under the same service). This _DNS entry_ is resolved inside the docker-bridge network.

Comment: The service is only reachable from other containers that reside in the same docker subnet. But when you specify the `-p source:dest`, a DNAT rule is created in the iptables of your host machine, that's telling your machine to forward all traffic incoming on tcp:5432 to the docker network at postgres-service:5432. The name is resolved, and finally that how the DB container is reached from the outside world